# JavaFX bind choicebox to a property in a collection

Tags: java, javafx

With JavaFX, what is the best way to bind `ChoiceBox` to properties of a collection?
In example below I try to bind `ChoiceBox` elements to `name` of an `ObservableList` `beans`. This works fine when items are added/removed **but not when the property value `name` change**.

I was hoping there is a clean and simple solution to this but haven't yet found any example of it...

The class `ExampleBean2` in deliberately not implemented with properties since that object may correspond to a external model class out of my control.

```java
package com.playground;

import org.controlsfx.control.PropertySheet;
import org.controlsfx.property.BeanPropertyUtils;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class BindingPlayGround extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXPlayGround");
        Parent content = createContentPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(content, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    protected Parent createContentPane() {
        ObservableList<BeanExample2> beans = FXCollections.observableArrayList();       
        ObservableList<PropertySheet> sheets = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ListView<PropertySheet> listView = new ListView<PropertySheet>(sheets);
        Button addBeanButton = new Button("Add Bean");
        addBeanButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                BeanExample2 e = new BeanExample2();
                e.setName("Name-not-set");
                PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet(BeanPropertyUtils.getProperties(e));
                sheets.add(propertySheet);
                beans.add(e);
            }
        });

        VBox vBar = new VBox();
        vBar.getChildren().add(listView);
        vBar.getChildren().add(addBeanButton);
                ObservableList<BeanExample2> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<BeanExample2, Observable[]>() {
            @Override
            public Observable[] call(BeanExample2 param) {
                return new Observable[]{new SimpleStringProperty(param, "name")};
            }
        });
        Bindings.bindContent(names, beans);

        Button addChoiceBoxButton = new Button("Add ChoiceBox");
        addChoiceBoxButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                ChoiceBox<BeanExample2> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<BeanExample2>(names);
                vBar.getChildren().add(choiceBox);
            }
        });
        vBar.getChildren().add(addChoiceBoxButton);
        return vBar;
    }

    static class BeanExample2 {       
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }        

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BeanExample2{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
ObservableList<BeanExample2> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<BeanExample2, Observable[]>() {
    @Override
    public Observable[] call(BeanExample2 param) {
        return new Observable[]{new SimpleStringProperty(param, "name")};
    }
});
```

you're creating a new property to listen to for updates that cannot be referenced except from the value returned by the `call` method. The only relationship between the `BeanExample2` instance and the `SimpleStringProperty` is that the `BeanExample2` instance is used as bean for the property, which has no effect besides being available via the `getBean()` method of the property. The value of the property is never assigned let alone modified on a change of the `BeanExample2` instance.

To properly trigger updates in the `ObservableList`, you need to make sure the element in the array returned by the above method is actually notified of updates. Usually you add the property to the class itself:

```
public static class BeanExample2 {

    public final String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public final void setName(String value) {
        this.name.set(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BeanExample2{"
                + "name='" + name.get() + '\''
                + '}';
    }

    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And return an array containing the property from the `Callback`

```
ObservableList<BeanExample2> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Callback<BeanExample2, Observable[]>() {
    @Override
    public Observable[] call(BeanExample2 param) {
        return new Observable[]{param.nameProperty()};
    }
});
```

Note that currently there seems to be a bug in `ChoiceBox` that adds entries for every intermediate value to the `ChoiceBox`.

`ComboBox` does not have this issue and could be used instead of a `ChoiceBox`.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks! 
Since the bean class won't be in my control I made simple adapter class for it:
`
public class BeanExample2Adapter extends BeanExample2 {

        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");

        public void setName(String nameProperty) {
            this.name.set(nameProperty);
        }


        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }
    }
`

Comment: @user2303720: You can hardly call that a adapter. A properly implemented adapter would wrap a `BeanExample2` instance listen to the changes of it's own property and calling the setter of the associated `BeanExample2` class, if the property is modified, see [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Object_Adapter_pattern)

Comment: Yes correct, it was a bad name.
Regarding the ChoiceBox problem - could be related to http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8088241